# Asterisk 11 /usr/sbin/asterisk not found

Tags: asterisk

I have tried to install Asterisk 11 in my Ubuntu, but all time when I finished the installation, my Asterisk stopped suddenly and when I type `asterisk -vvvvvvvvr` it return `/usr/sbin/asterisk not found`

I also tried

You can fix this issue by compiling asterisk again.
do this:
cd /usr/src/asterisk-version
make distclean
make clean
./configure
make menuselect
make install

but not succeeded

What can happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern version you should do

```
  ldconfig
```

After install of asterisk. If you install it in /usr/local/ path, you also should put /usr/local/lib/ into /etc/ld.so.conf.d/asterisk before that.

You can get info where you installed asterisk binary by using find utility

```
find / -name asterisk
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure asterisk with prefix

e.g

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
```

and then try

```
make && make install
```

and set the path variable appropriately to

e.g export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin/

Answer (score 1):

```
whereis asterisk
```

if not found then it was not installed.

Answer (score -1):

try restarting the service after install, once it stops

> asterisk restart